# how to count this values?

Tags: java, string

I have several lines such as this :

```
AAAAAABBBBDDDAAADDSSDD,FLAGE=TRUE,LLUUGJYFR
TTT:1
TTT:2
AAAAAABBBBDDDAAADDSSDD,FLAGE=TRUE,YYTTREETU,YTTREFF
TTT:1
AAAAAABBBBDDDAAADDSSDD,FLAGE=TRUE,KKIFRDEEW,YTRFHFFD
TTT:1
TTT:2
TTT:3
TTT:4
AAAAAABBBBDDDAAADDSSDD,FLAGE=FALSE,TYYRFFGGGFD,JJUUGGGGF
TTT:1
TTT:2
AAAAAABBBBDDDAAADDSSDD,FLAGE=TRUE,KKYGG,GGRFFFF,KUUYFFF
TTT:1
```

I want to count TTT and FLAG=TRUE if the FLAG=TRUE in java
how can I check it ?
thanks for your help

Comment: Is this a Java question?

Comment: not useful question without any research effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code below might help you.

```
int res1 = countString(yourinput , "FLAGE=TRUE");
int res2 = countString(yourinput , "TTT");

int res3 = countTrueTTT(yourinput  , "FLAGE" , "TTT")

public int countString(String yourString , String search){ 
      int sLen = search.length;
  int len = yourString.length;
  int count = 0;
  int index = yourString.indexOf(search, 0);
  while(index > 0){
    count++;
    index = yourString.indexOf(search, index + sLen);
  }

  return count;
}

public int countTrueTTT(String yourString , String under , String search){
   int len = yourString.length;
      int sLen = under.length;
      int count = 0;
      int index = yourString.indexOf(under+"=TRUE" , 0);
      int nextIndex = yourString.indexOf(under , index+sLen);
      while(index > 0 && nextIndex > 0){
        count += countString(yourString.subString(index,nextIndex),search);

        index = yourString.indexOf(under+"=TRUE" , index+sLen);
        nextIndex = yourString.indexOf(under , index+sLen);
        if(nextIndex <0)
          nextIndex = yourString.length;
      }
      return count;
}
```

Comment: Edited answer but didnt compile the code. There might be syntax problem. But it explains the solution.

Comment: index = yourString.indexOf(under+"=TRUE" , index); This line should return -1 if it can not find. Check for values.

Comment: Edited solution, i think this ll fix the problem. Added sLen to indexes.

Comment: not important really. There was a for loop, that left from there.

Comment: Didnt have time to compile and test, but edited solution. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
var lines = ["here", "are", "your", "lines"];
var count = 0;
for(i in lines) {
    var line = lines[i];
    if( /(^TTT:)|(FLAGE=TRUE)/.test(line) ) {
        count++;
    }
}

alert(count);
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, thought it is javascript..
But you got the idea. Using regex.